# Compiling C code with VLD

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, sdl, visual-leak-detector

I'm trying to compile the SDL libraries with Visual C++ (2010), and with Visual Leak Detector as to find a memory leak in another program that calls SDL.

The problem is that vld.h is a C++ library, and SDL.c is a C program. Accordingly, when I #include , the source doesn't compile as VLD seems to use a C++ specific constructs:

```
typedef int (__cdecl * VLD_REPORT_HOOK)(int reportType, wchar_t *message, int *returnValue);

__declspec(dllimport) int VLDSetReportHook(int mode,  VLD_REPORT_HOOK pfnNewHook);
```

I've attempted compiling SDL.c as a C++ program, but I get a plethora of errors.

Is there any way I can include VLD in SDL?

Comment: What is the C++ specific construct? I don't see anything C++-specific in that code.

Comment: I'm not sure (I've only ever done C++, and I'm not great at it). I assumed that was the code. It compiles in a C++ program, but when in SDL.C, it creates the following errors:

1>c:\program files (x86)\visual leak detector\include\vld_def.h(44): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
1>c:\program files (x86)\visual leak detector\include\vld_def.h(44): error C2081: 'wchar_t' : name in formal parameter list illegal
1>c:\program files (x86)\visual leak detector\include\vld_def.h(44): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'

Comment: 1>c:\program files (x86)\visual leak detector\include\vld_def.h(44): error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
1>c:\program files (x86)\visual leak detector\include\vld_def.h(44): error C2059: syntax error : ')'

Comment: The only other place where it fails was just edited into the question.

Comment: Looks like it's complaining about wchar_t, you should #include <wchar.h>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(with thanks to @Matias Valdenegro)

The problem was the `wchar_t`. To be able to recompile SDL (and I assume other C source files) to include VLD, add

```
#include <wchar.h>
```

to both `vld.h` and `vld_def.h`. SDL will then happily compile, and can be used with an SDL program to detect memory leaks stemming from Surfaces and the like.

Comment: Alternatively, put #include <wchar.h> before #include <vld.h>